# How can I disambiguate a mixed Iterator and Futures call chain without moving self?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to add a Futures `Stream` implementation to an existing struct which already has a synchronous `Iterator` implementation. In order to keep the code DRY, I want to modify the `Iterator` implementation to call the new `Stream` implementation and wait on it.

I modeled my implementation of `Iterator` after [the code sample for `Stream::by_ref`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.21/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.by_ref):

```
stream.by_ref().take(2)
```

My implementation wound up looking like this:

```
impl Iterator for Websocket {
    type Item = Message;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.by_ref().take(1).wait().next().and_then(Result::ok)
    }
}
```

However I get an error with multiple applicable items:

```
error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
   --> src/websocket/websocket.rs:330:14
    |
330 |         self.by_ref().take(1).wait().next().and_then(Result::ok)
    |              ^^^^^^ multiple `by_ref` found
    |
note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl of the trait `websocket::websocket::futures::Stream` for the type `websocket::websocket::Websocket`
   --> src/websocket/websocket.rs:149:1
    |
149 | impl Stream for Websocket {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl of the trait `std::iter::Iterator` for the type `websocket::websocket::Websocket`
   --> src/websocket/websocket.rs:324:1
    |
324 | impl Iterator for Websocket {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #3 is defined in the trait `std::io::Write`
    = help: to disambiguate the method call, write `std::io::Write::by_ref(&mut self)` instead
```

The methods I wanted to call from left to right are:

- [`Stream::by_ref`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.21/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.by_ref)
- [`Stream::take`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.21/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.take)
- [`Stream::wait`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.21/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.wait)
- [`Iterator::next`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next)
- [`Option::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then)
- [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok)

If I disambiguate the code it looks like this:

```
impl Iterator for Websocket {
    type Item = Message;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        <Self as Stream>::take(*<Self as Stream>::by_ref(self),1).wait().next().and_then(Result::ok)
    }
}
```

However then I get a lifetime error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
   --> src/websocket/websocket.rs:331:32
    |
331 |         <Self as Stream>::take(*<Self as Stream>::by_ref(self),1).wait().next().and_then(Result::ok)
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

How do I make this unambiguous but keep the ability to call `take` on the result of `by_ref`?

I know there's a new version of Futures, but I can't use it due to other libraries I'm using needing to be API compatible with the version of Futures I use.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Ideally, produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org).

Comment: *I get a lifetime error* — that's not a lifetime error, FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid moving out of the borrowed value by not attempting to move out of the borrowed value:

```
extern crate futures;

use futures::prelude::*;

struct Message;
struct Websocket;

impl Stream for Websocket {
    type Item = Message;
    type Error = ();

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Result<Async<Option<Self::Item>>, Self::Error> {
        Err(())
    }
}

impl Iterator for Websocket {
    type Item = Message;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let a = Stream::take(self, 1);
        let mut b = a.wait();
        let c = Iterator::next(&mut b);
        c.and_then(Result::ok)
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

There's no need to call `Stream::by_ref` since the starting type is already a `&mut Websocket`, so I've removed it.

You can recombine these to one line if desired:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    Stream::take(self, 1)
        .wait()
        .next()
        .and_then(Result::ok)
}
```